# How do I get git-blame and log to ignore line wrap changes?

Tags: git

I would like a log of changes, and a blame annotation, which ignores changes in line wrapping.  For example...

```
-This is the hardest part of testing, where do you start?  People often
-get overwhelmed at the apparent enormity of the task of testing a
-whole module.  Best place to start is at the beginning.  Date::ICal is
-an object-oriented module, and that means you start by making an
-object.  So we test C<new()>.
+This is the hardest part of testing, where do you start?  People often get
+overwhelmed at the apparent enormity of the task of testing a whole module.
+The best place to start is at the beginning.  C<Date::ICal> is an
+object-oriented module, and that means you start by making an object.  Test
+C<new()>.
```

There is very little content changed there, but the log and blame will show it all changed.  This both makes patches difficult to review and gets in the way of tools which check the age of code.

`-w` is insufficient.

**UPDATE**: I've got half the answer: `git log -p --word-diff` covers logging.

Answer (score 0):

You'd pretty much have to write your own diff tool. The diff tool used by default in Git (and most diff tools, for that matter) do line-by-line diffs, which aren't going to have a way to do what you want.

Comment: I don't believe this is true.  git-diff has --word-diff which even has a script-friendly format.

Comment: I was referring more to the blame component of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since git v1.4.3 you can use the diff option `--color-words` to show inline changes, ignoring newlines, e.g.:

```
git log -p --color-words
```

And since git 1.7.2 there is the more general `--word-diff` option, which also can output similar inline diffs but marking the differences in plain text rather than with colours.

As far as I know you can't do anything like this with `git blame`.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of --color-words.  Might be easier on the eyes than --word-diff.