# git diff - ignore all linefeeds between revisions

Tags: git

A team member used automated source formatting in eclipse and commited the code with the source code formatting.
I want a way to see only what they changed in code... not the muckup of everything.

I'm running the following command:

```
$ git diff -b -w comit1234 commit5678
```

I still get the following:

```
-       private final ArrayList<Application> preparedApps = new
-                       ArrayList<Application>(100);
-       private final ArrayList<Application> sponsoredApps = new
-                       ArrayList<Application>(100);
-       private final ArrayList<Application> nonSponsoredApps = new
-                       ArrayList<Application>(100);
+       private final ArrayList<Application> preparedApps = new ArrayList<Applic
+                       100);
+       private final ArrayList<Application> sponsoredApps = new ArrayList<Appli
+                       100);
+       private final ArrayList<Application> nonSponsoredApps = new ArrayList<Ap
+                       100);
```

Is there a command to ignore changes like this?

Comment: I've been searching for about an hour on the internet... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how the lines are wrapped.

If those lines are on several *lines*, [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) will always detect those as different before/after reformat, because the diff is done line by line, as mentioned in "[How do I get git-blame and log to ignore line wrap changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7864882/6309)".

Comment: So no solutions for such a seemingly simple problem? I did a lot of searching and noticed you have to use word by word diff (like wdiff).

Comment: @maythesource.com I am not aware of a multi-line diff for git: the issue here is that changes are on multiple lines.